# How to find intersection point of two 3D lines

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, 3d

I know the $x,y,z$ values of the 4 points that create two lines. I also know the $x,y$ value of the crossing point. How do I get the $z$ of the crossing point?

Comment: do you have an example of your Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given four points $\mathbf{a,b,c,d}$, form the parametric equations

$\mathbf{a}+t \mathbf{(b-a)}$ and $\mathbf{c}+s \mathbf{(d-c)}$, where $s,t \in \mathbb R$ are parameters.

This will look like $\ell_1:=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)+t(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2,b_3-a_3) \mid t \in \mathbb R\}$, and analogous for $\ell_2$.

If you know the $x,y$ values for the intersection, then there is a system of linear equations:

$x=a_1+t(b_1-a_1)=c_1+s(d_1-c_1)$ and $y=a_2+t(b_2-a_2)=c_1+s(d_2-c_2)$. Solve these for $s,t$ and plug them back into the parametric equations to get the $z$ value.

Comment: But if I know the two x,y values where they will intersect, from this I can get the s and t right? like if two end points for one line is (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2). And the crossing point is (x,y,z). Then s = (x-x1)/(x2-x1). Similar for t right?

Comment: Well, you know that $x_1+s(x_2-x_1)$ is a collection of points on the line. If you know $(x,y,z)$ then you can see $x=x_1+s(x_2-x_1)$ and solve for $s$, this will be the time parameter that "gets you to the point."

Comment: I suppose you are done here as well, since you can already plug $s$ back in. I guess the method I mentioned just gives you all possible intersection points.

Comment: If ab is horizontal and cd is vertical then the equation becomes, x = a1 + t(b1-a1) = c1 and y = a2 = c1 + s(d2-c2). The terms (d1-c1) and (b2-a2) is 0. How to solve for s and t from these equations?